# How to expose views filter on nodereference cck field on node create

Tags: drupal

I am looking for a way to utilize an exposed views filter for a cck node reference field. I have tried a couple of items that just don't seem to cut or I have not been able to configure them.

The goal would be when creating a page the nodereference field would not be a select field with hundreds of options, but would be an exposed filter view for a particular content type. The exposed filter would allow you to filter by title or by a content taxonomy field.

I have tried nodereference explorer which could work but I have found it to be pretty buggy for a production site.

I have also tried nodereference view select, which appears to work differently for D6 than in D5.

It could be that I have the right elements but have yet to get them integrated successfully.

Comment: I use nodereference view select for the same reason. It allows users to search nodes by title and that is enough for my tasks. Do you interested for me to provide step-by-step setup for this? Or you need exactly "exposed filter view" for you task and searching by title is not enough for you?